# System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable does not contain a definition for 'ToList'

Tags: .net, linq, generics, collections

Now this one has me stumped and so I would appreciate some help please. I have this code tested in .NET 4.0 application, and it works fine. However, when I move it back to my 3.5 environment, I get the following error message when I build.

**System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable  does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments**

And the code it complains of is the following

```
 List<String> PathValues = GetReportValues(settings.DirectoryDefinition.NameTokens.OrderBy(x => x.Index).ToList<Token>());
```

The signature for the GetReportValues method is as below

```
 private List<String> GetReportValues(List<Token> TokenList)
{
   List<String> PathValues = new List<String>();
/// code goes here
  return PathValues;
}
```

and for NameTokens, I have

```
   [XmlElement(Type = typeof(List<DirectoryPatternToken>))]
    public List<DirectoryPatternToken> NameTokens { get; set; }
```

The **DirectoryDefinition.NameTokens** object is a list containing objects derived from Token class. GetReportValues simply takes a list of tokens, of which DirectoryDefinition

```
 [Serializable]
public class DirectoryPatternToken : Token
{


}
```

As I explained earlier, this tests well in .NET 4.0. How can I get this working in 3.5 please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you not pass the collection into the function as an IOrderedenumerable?

Answer (score 2):

Change `.ToList<Token>()` to `.ToList<string>()`

or simply write it as `.ToList()`

or do not use it at all, since your method already returns `List<string>`

Comment: The Token objects are not simply strings. Token is infact itself a complex type here.

Comment: @Kobojunkie you wrote: `The signature for the GetReportValues method is as below: private **List<String>** GetReportValues(......)`

Comment: Yes, it returns a list of strings however it does not take a list of strings

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<DirectoryPatternToken> tokens = 
             settings.DirectoryDefinition.NameTokens.OrderBy(x => x.Index).ToList();
 List<string> pathValues = GetReportValues(tokens);
```

from which you can extract the string properties

Comment: NameTokens is a generic List of DirectoryPatternToken objects which are derived from Token class.

Comment: ToList() causes the GetReportValues to complain of invalid argument. So ToList() does not work.

Comment: @Kobojunkie, this statement returns the list of tokens from which you can extract the strings

Comment: ERROR: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DirectoryPatternToken>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Token>

Comment: Note that GetReportValues could probably take a IEnumerable in parameter instead of a List

Comment: It is not complaining really about the IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

C# 4.0 implemented a feature called generic covariance:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.100).aspx

This allows a List< DirectoryPatternToken > to be treated as a List< Token > since DirectoryPatternToken derives from Token. Since C# 3.5 does not have this feature, you would have to use these lines to make your code compile:

```
List<String> PathValues = GetReportValues(NameTokens.OrderBy(x => x.index).ToList<DirectoryPatternToken>());

private static List<String> GetReportValues(List<DirectoryPatternToken> TokenList)
```

Answer (score 0):

The ToList method you are looking for is an extension method. Try adding this using directive to the top of your file:

using System.Linq;By adding this using directive you are indicating to the compiler that any extension methods in that namespace should be imported.